# How to retain datagrid ordering asc/desc by column after reload VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I have datagrid populated from Access database every 60 seconds in timer_tick() subroutine.

```
Dim direction As SortOrder
.
.
.
```

DataGridView1 ColumnHeaderMouseClick code :

```
direction = DataGridView1.SortOrder
MsgBox(direction.ToString())
```

Now, every other click it shows descending and other half '2' , just number insted of Ascending.
Does anyone know why that is happening or how to fix it?

What I try to achieve is to retain sortorder after datagrid is automatically reloaded within timer tick() sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1617798

Problem was that
DataGridView.SortOrder returns a value of Windows.Forms.SortOrder
(this variable type will retrieve current sort order)

whilst

DataGridView.Sort() is looking for a value of System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection
(this variable type will set new sort order)

So we need something like:

```
columnXY = DataGridView1.SortedColumn
*' if no column set for sort use third one *
        If columnXY Is Nothing Then
            columnXY = DataGridView1.Columns(2)
        End If

Dim SetSortOrder As ListSortDirection
Dim GridSortOrder As SortOrder
GridSortOrder = DataGridView1.SortOrder

        If GridSortOrder = Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending Then
            SetSortOrder = ListSortDirection.Ascending
        ElseIf GridSortOrder = Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending Then
            SetSortOrder = ListSortDirection.Descending
        ElseIf GridSortOrder = Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None Then
            SetSortOrder = ListSortDirection.Ascending
        Else : GridSortOrder = ListSortDirection.Ascending
            MsgBox("not good")
        End If

DataGridView1.DataSource = datasetXY.Tables(0)
DataGridView1.Sort(columnXY, SetSortOrder)
```

Now the items in datagrid will remain ordered by the same column and ascending/descending after reload.